# Encode and Decode a Class in ios

Tags: ios, swift, swifty-json

I have a class

```
class Event{
  var name:String = "";
  var attributes:[String:Any] = [:];
  var lineItems:[LineItem] = [];
}

class LineItem {
  var itemName:String = "";
  var details:[String:Any] = [:];
}
```

I want to convert it into json string and json string back to model.

I try

```
var test = Event()
    test.name = "jogi"
    var dictionary = Dictionary<String,Any>();
    dictionary.updateValue("shoes", forKey: "item")
    dictionary.updateValue(345, forKey: "amount")
    test.attributes = dictionary


    let json = JSON(test)
```

But it give an error of unsupported Type because swiftyjson support only    `rawArray`,`rawDictionary`,`rawString`,`rawNumber`,`rawNull`,`rawBool`.

Answer (score 2):

You could make your Class conform to `Codable` protocol

```
class Event: Codable {
  var name:String = "";
  var attributes:[String:Any] = [:];
  var lineItems:[LineItem] = [];
}
```

Then to encode your model use:

```
try? JSONEncoder().encode(event)
```

To decode your model use

```
try? JSONDecoder().decode(Event.self, from: eventData)
```

Comment: Make it inherit from ```Codable```.

Comment: Type 'Event' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable' I found out that Any does not implement codable.

Comment: This is not *inheritance*, it's *conformance* to a protocol. Swift is then able to synthesize the decoding initializer and the `encode` method.

Comment: @fphilipe when Event confirm to Codable protocol then its give 2 error Type 'Event' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'  and 'Encodable'

Comment: @jogendra Since you are using SwiftyJSON, try to change `attributes` type to `JSON` to make it conform to Codable protocol.